# Is It Possible To Perform A SQL Database Query As Part Of A WebConfig URL Rewrite Rule?

Tags: .htaccess, azure, url-rewriting, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently in the process of migrating a PHP website from LAMP Hosting to Microsoft Azure Web Apps Hosting.

The site being migrated uses HTAccess for URL Rewriting purposes; however from what I can tell, Azure does not support the use of HTAccess files (please correct me if I am wrong in this) - instead, it appears that I must use IIS WebConfig for this purposes (a technology that I am not overly familiar with).

Assuming that I have to rewrite the file from HTAccess to WebConfig, the HTAccess file to be rewritten uses Mod_Rewrite and external Rewrite Maps as part of the URL rewriting process. The HTAccess Rewrite Map performs a Database Query as part of this process whereby a URL such as *www.example.com/category/music* is inputted and then re-written to *www.example.com/category.php?catID=1*, i.e. *the ID associated with each category name is identified via a Database query*.

I've familiarised myself with the basics of Web Config and IIS Rewrite Maps thus far; however I have only encountered tutorials outlining [static rewrite rules](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module).

Is it possible to perform database queries using IIS Config - similar to the HT Access scenario outlined above?

If so, can someone please point me in the direction of some tutorials dealing with the topic or provide some sample code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a tutorial that deals this topic [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that article answers your question but the right way would be using IIS manager on a windows machine to convert from mod rewite rules to urlrewrite config as detailed in https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules